# Upload custom DV certificate on cloudflare

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, cloudflare

I have already a DV (Domain Validation) Certificate SSL
I want to upload my certificate to cloudflare. But, I want to know, cloudflare supports DV certificate or not? If cloudflare supports this i will purchase business plan account
There are someone experience from this case?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you asked cloudflare? They might provide the only real valid answer

Comment: @AndréSchild Unfortunately, the cloudflare support team answer our questions too late

Comment: Then it's perhaps not the right partner for your business

Comment: Andre, CloudFlare answer questions based on how much you pay, hence why business customers get quicker responses. Optimised Partners and Enterprise clients get even faster responses than Business clients.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, but [only on Business plans](https://www.cloudflare.com/plans) where [you can upload your own certificate](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170466-How-do-I-upload-a-custom-SSL-certificate-Business-or-Enterprise-only-).